# Recommendations for HTML/Ajax multiple select with autocomplete library or plugin

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I'm looking for a library or jquery plugin (etc) for a dynamic, multi-value form selector.  **Think of gmail's "TO" field when composing email.**

Looking for:

- Populate field(s) with 0 to n employee ids.
- Currently have 5000 employees.
- First or last name searching.

I've rolled my own in the past.  However I'm trying to focus my development time on specific business problems.

Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, This is what I think of when I think multiple select: http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-multiselect-plugin-with-themeroller-support/ whereas what you're looking for would be some form of multiple autocomplete ala http://jquery.bassistance.de/autocomplete/demo/

Comment: Yes, the jquery.bassistance.de/autocomplete/demo with "multiple items" is close to what I'm looking for, but it does not constrain the user to the suggestions. Mix the searching/suggestions of auto-complete with the constrains of a select input is what I'm looking for.

Comment: have you ever found something to satisfy your needs? I've been looking exactly for the same thing (at least I hope so) through quite a lot of options, but none that are quite that gmail's flavor.

Comment: @Cawas No I haven't. :(  I've started playing with GWT, and it might help me role my own (again).

Comment: that is sad news... But if you're rolling your own, I'd highly advice using the already suggested Eric's code on jquery - it's working amazingly well, very fine-tuned and it's almost there. As I've said else where, just mixing up Eric with **devthought's textboxlist**  ( http://devthought.com/wp-content/projects/mootools/textboxlist/Demo/ ) and adding a regular "first and last name searching" to it, which can probably be done using regular jquery autocomplete.

Comment: Please refer this [http://www.shawndean.net/projects/MultiSelect%20Autocomplete/](http://www.shawndean.net/projects/MultiSelect%20Autocomplete/)

Comment: @LanceRushing If you really want a well performing web app, then I would stay away from libraries such as jQuery, they are slow due to the extensive functionality and sometimes even a little buggy. Especially because you can get much smaller libraries to solve your specific problems, whereof some of them are better written.
Also if you have any sort of mobile clients, the jQuery library is a big unneeded download.
I will have to look through some stuff to find you a demo of the other libraries, so it might take a bit.
Also I recommend learning AJAX and JSON for future problems like this. :)

Comment: You can try Chosen plugin for jquery [http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) very easy to use.

Comment: Twitter just open sourced their own jQuery plugin `typeahead` for this: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js